# mute and unmute the sound of my active application

Tags: android, audio

i build an app , and i want to mute and unmute just the sound of this app..
i found this code to mute the sound:

```
    AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    aManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

It mutes all the sound of the device and disables the setting of the device to set the sound, not just the sound of the app..
And i found this code to unmute the sound:

```
    AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    aManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
```

When i have muted the sound, and i clicked the button that contains this code, this code is not running and the sound setting of my device is still disabled..
I just want to mute and unmute the sound of my app, not my device.. Any correction?

Comment: With current information, I cannot pinpoint the source of the issue. However, on the documentation it is stated that `The mute requests for a given stream are cumulative: the AudioManager can receive several mute requests from one or more clients and the stream will be unmuted only when the same number of unmute requests are received.`. Currently, I can only guess that you may have called the code to mute more than to unmute.

Comment: Other than that, I can only give a suggestion to use a global volume modifier for your app, like `float volModifier = 1.0f` and use it in conjunction with `playSoundEffect(effectType, volume*volModifer)`. Set `volModifier = 0.0f` if it is "mute", or just don't play the sound at all.

Comment: i think you're right about the amount of mute code and unmute code.. but i don't really understand about volModifier, can you explain more about this code in answer? so then i can accept your answer :D

Comment: @AndrewT. i have used MediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0) to mute and MediaPlayer.setVolume(1,1) to unmute, but it forces the app off..

Comment: Uhh, my second comment was nonsense regarding to `playSoundEffect()`. Just ignore it... but basically, my idea was just like what you have done. Also, could you post your stack trace/LogCat? Also, sorry for not providing any code, since I'm not experienced in `AudioManager` and `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: there was no error about that code.. i just put this mute and unmute button in my MainActivity, and my fault is to set the default button as mute, so if i have already press mute, it automatically changes to unmute button, and if i move to another layout and go back to the MainActivity, the button is still mute button, so the condition is i have click mute button twice and unmute button once.. Can i create a condition to check if AudioManager is muted or not, so if it was muted, i can display the unmute button? :D

Comment: If that's the issue, then you can use `SharedPreference` to store whether it is currently muted or not. Then you check the state inside `onResume()` and set the `Button` based on the value.

Comment: So i have fixed some of my codes, and when i click mute button, it muted and when i click unmute, it unmuted.. But when i click mute, and i move to another layout which contains media player, it is true that the music is muted, but when i went back to the MainActivity, to unmute the sound, it cannot be unmuted anymore.. i don't know why it happened.. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button play, mute, data, max;
private boolean VolIsMute;
AudioManager manager;
int currentVolume;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    VolIsMute = false;
    init();
}
public void isMute() {
    if (VolIsMute) {
        manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        VolIsMute = false;
    } else {
        manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        VolIsMute = true;
    }
}
public void init() {
    max = (Button) findViewById(R.id.max);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    mute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mute);
    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(
                        getApplicationContext(), R.raw.abc);
                mp.start();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("WTF", "error: " + e);
            }

        }
    });
}
public void mute(View view) {
    currentVolume = manager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    if (currentVolume == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                " Volume is " + currentVolume +"Press unmute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        isMute();
    }
}
public void checvol(View view) {

    currentVolume = manager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    if (currentVolume != 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Press unmute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        isMute();
    }
}
}
```

> I used two buttons one for mute and other for unmute.
>   Check the current volume first and then do appropriately with if -else.

For those who simplify this,don't forget to post the code.