# mute/unmute volume in android app

Tags: android-audiomanager

i set toggle button for audio.. 
The mute audio work good but unmute audio doesnt work good..
 when i unmute.. it unmute the audio only after restarting the app..

by using this code

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);


//unmute audio

AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            //
             //
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
```

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908962/setstreammute-never-unmutes

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943254/mute-and-unmute-the-sound-of-my-active-application